# How to formally prove whether this function is onto or not?$ K(x) = x^ 2$ where $x \ge 0$.

Tags: number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

$K(x) = x^2.$
The domain and range of this function comprise of non-negative real numbers.
If it were real numbers instead of "non-negative" real numbers, then it seems easy to prove it by counterexample. The range includes negative integers but their square root can't be represented as real number. It is complex number and so, the function is not onto function.

But in case of "non-negative" real numbers, it is easy to see that the range will include only positive real numbers (and 0). And intuitively it seems obvious that square root of positive real numbers is another positive real number. So, the function should be onto. 
However, how do I formally show this statement? I am assuming the intuition I presented in the earlier paragraph doesn't qualify as formal proof.

Comment: The main thing in the formal proof will be the defintion of "onto".  So, start by writing down that defintion.

Comment: "the range will include only positive real numbers."

Why?  Don't we have $K(0) = 0$?

Comment: One can use some tools from the Calculus (Intermediate Value Theorem) to show that every non-negative number has a square root. One can also prove it from the more basic fact that the reals have the Least Upper Bound Property.

Comment: @avs yes, but it easily handled as square root of 0 is 0 which is again non-negative real number. I agree it is not perfect to say that "the range will include only positive real numbers".

Comment: To prove that it is onto is **not** a matter of showing every square is non neg real; you need to prove every non, neg real is a square root. I.E. for every x; 0 <= x then there exists a y; y >= 0 such that f (y) = \sqr (y) = x.

Comment: Andre nichols.  Who don't need to show every non neg has a square root to show it is onto, do we?  (We do have to show that to show the function is defined,though).  To show the function is onto we have to show instead that every non neg is a square root, don't we.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*  A function $f:X\to Y$ is onto if for each $y\in Y$ there exists an $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.

If $K:\Bbb{R}^+_0\to \Bbb{R}^+_0$ via $K(x)=x^2$.

If we pick a $y$ non-negative, what $x$ gives us $K(x)=x^2=y$?

Comment: I think it should be negative, instead of positive.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, it means that I've to then prove that every non-negative number has a square root which is itself a non-negative number, right? If yes, I don't know how to do that. It seems too trivial at first.

Comment: @aste123 If just from rules of indices you know what the answer is. If you do want to prove that every non-negative real has a square root, it is the opposite of trivial as Spivak's book on Calculus mentions and I refer to here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1384533/128967. The way to do this would involve writing down axioms for the real numbers, defining continuity, proving polynomials or at least quadratics are continuous. Then prove the intermediate value theorem. Then for $a\in\Bbb{R}^+_0$ apply the intermediate value theorem to $f_a(x)=x^2-a$. $f(0)<0$, and either $f(1)>0$ or $f(a)>0$.

Comment: That or $a=1$ and $\sqrt{1}=1$.

Comment: In that case, how do I satisfy the question without proving all that? Your first sentence says something about indices which seem a bit hard to comprehend for me. Maybe there is a typing mistake in that sentence. Can you tell me how the rules of indices can help here? Thank you :)

Comment: Will something like showing square root of 0 is 0 and with increasing the the non-negative number, its square root also increases. So it has to remain inside the positive range seem good? I don't know how irrationality will affect this method.

Comment: @aste123 As in $a^b \cdot a^c=a^{b+c}$, and $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$, so $(y^{1/2})^2=y$. That's what I was implying by laws of indices, and we call $y^{1/2}$ a square root. As another note, is $H:\mathbb{Q}_0^+\to \Bbb{Q}_0^+$, with $H(x)=x^2$ onto? Where $\Bbb{Q}_0^+$ is the non-negative rationals. Maybe this will emphasise that we need something extra in our proof (at least in tackling it a bit more formally).

Comment: @aste123 May I ask where you found the question, and that might indicate the level of answer the asker requires?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling thanks for that!

Comment: @snulty Discrete mathematics by Susanna S. Epp

Comment: @aste123 I had a quick look and I believe, judging by the chapter, that Susanna S. Epp would be happy if your proof went as Deepsea describes. In chapter $7$ she mentions that to show logarithm and exponential functions were 1-1 and onto with respective domains and images you would need methods of calculus. But since methods of calculus are not discussed I would say the expected answer is for you to say $f(\sqrt{y})=y$. If you do want to dive deeper into this, you could ask for a reference for a calculus book or analysis book to see how the more formal proof would look?

Answer (score 2):

Recall definition of an onto function $f: A \to B$: $\forall y \in B, \exists x \in A: f(x) = y$. Thus for any $ y \in \mathbb{R^{+}}\cup \{0\}$, choose $x = \sqrt{y}\implies x \ge 0 \implies f(x) = f(\sqrt{y}) = (\sqrt{y})^2 = y $. Thus $f$ is onto.

Comment: (+1) as I think this answer is what the (book) author of the question had in mind.